# Get Controller instance from Node

Tags: javafx

There is an possibility to get Controller instance from Node ??  for example AnchorPane on Tab ?

I have  some AnchorPanes where I load different Controllers and I would like to verify which controller is already loaded

Comment: May be this is helpful to you. [passing-parameters-javafx-fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/40193164#40193164)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Node`s do not contain any information about a controller used with the fxml file used to create it by default, since fxml is just one way of creating a scene. However you could attach information like this to the `userData`/`properties` in the fxml:

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" onMouseClicked="#click" fx:controller="fxml.FXMLController">
    <!-- store controller as userData property -->
    <userData>
        <fx:reference source="controller" />
    </userData>
    <properties>
        <!-- store controller at key "foo" in properties map -->
        <foo><fx:reference source="controller" /></foo> 
    </properties>
</AnchorPane>
```

If you do this, you can lookup the controller at closest ancestor of a node where you added this kind of information using

```
public static Object getController(Node node) {
    Object controller = null;
    do {
        controller = node.getProperties().get("foo");
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (controller == null && node != null);
    return controller;
}
```

to retrieve the info from the `properties` map or using

```
public static Object getController(Node node) {
    Object controller = null;
    do {
        controller = node.getUserData();
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (controller == null && node != null);
    return controller;
}
```

to retrieve the info from the `userData` property.

You should probably use just one way of adding the info though, not both. Also it would be better to replace `foo` as key...

Comment: Digging up this question... First thanks because it solved my problem, second it appears that using this type of markup breaks the scene builder :(
The problem seems to be with using subelements under properties. Using attributes like abc="123" doesn't break the scene builder, but you can't use fx:reference with this method.
So if I want to use the scene builder I need to comment out the controller property, edit the scene, and uncomment it when I'm done. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but if you have a main window, where you include other fxml files like this:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="MainController">
<!--  <HBox></HBox>, some elements here, your normal usual FXML-->
  <fx:include fx:id="someAnchorPane" source="SomeAnchorPane.fxml"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

and your `SomeAnchorPane.fxml` has `fx:controller` property set to `SomeOtherController`, then you can add a controller field in your `MainController` like this:

```
@FXML private SomeOtherController someAnchorPaneController;
```

And it will inject appropriate controller in this field automatically.

The key thing here is that your field has to be *named* "fx:id+Controller" for it to work.